# How to add/delete listener from listener container at run time

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I want to know how can we add/delete some listener from listener container at run time.

I have configured listener container as below :

```
<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory">
  <rabbit:listener ref="Listener0" queues="ListenerQueue0" />
  <rabbit:listener ref="Listener1" queues="ListenerQueue1" />
  <rabbit:listener ref="Listener2" queues="ListenerQueue2" />
```

One method comes to mind is we can add/remove 'rabbit:listener' from xml at run time and refresh application context, so new config will be loaded. 
Is this good way of doing ?

Please let me know other suggestions as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the approach you describe.

Each `<rabbit:listener/>` child element is actually a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`, the `<rabbit:listener-container/>` is just syntactic sugar to provide common attributes for the "child" containers.

If your listener is a POJO (i.e. not a `MessageListener`), wrap it in a `MessageListenerAdapter`.

So, you can simply create a new `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` at runtime - be sure to call `afterPropertiesSet()` after configuring it and then `start()`.